# Regex, split all last names into single group

Tags: regex, split, regex-group

I need to split a full name. I know that this question has been asked again and again, but I cannot find the solution that I need.

https://regex101.com/r/PvDIPA/1

I have a full name: 'Firstname Middlename Lastname'

And I need all except the first name to be put in to group 1

I have tried this RegEx: (\s+\S*)$    But it only put's the 'Lastname' in group 1, I need 'Middlename Lastname' to be in group 1.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something as simple as: `(\s+\S*){2}$`?
https://regex101.com/r/PvDIPA/2

Note that this only works if someone has one middle name.

Perhaps this suits you better: `^\w+((?:\h+\w+)+)$`
https://regex101.com/r/PvDIPA/4

Note that I have used `\h` here instead of `\s` since I am using regex101 with `//gm` flags, so `\s` would have also matched the end-of-line resulting in the first match also eating the second line.

Answer (score 0):

`[^ ]+ +((?:\w+ *){1,2})`

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4XFPC/1)

**Usage**

`[^ ]+ +`  *match everything up to and including the first occurrences of a space character*

`((?:\w+ *){1,2})` *capture 1 or 2 occurrences of any alpha-numeric chars followed by zero or more space chars (the outer brackets are the capturing group, the inner brackets with `?:` are a non-capturing group See the more full explanation at the demo page)*

Also allows for more than 1 space to be present between the names